# Number of objects in Amazon S3 (most efficient way)

Tags: performance, amazon-s3

Right now I am migrating to Amazon S3 from standard server. In current server, I have to set structure of directories in order to stay more efficient. For example, current structure of directory is: category_id/article_id/year/month/day/article_image.jpg and so on.

So, do I need to create such structure in the bucket of Amazon S3. Does it affect speed of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on your needs. The path itself is not important for S3, but you may prefer to find all images used in a specific category, on a specific date etc. So I would approach this from your management side, not from the performance side.

That said, if you have a lot of requests (like more than 50 requests per second), you might think of another way to organize your folder structure. [Here is a posting on the AWS blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html) that gives some examples to get the best performance out of S3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from [faq](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> Q: How is Amazon S3 data organized? Amazon S3 is a simple key-based
>   object store. When you store data, you assign a unique object key that
>   can later be used to retrieve the data. Keys can be any string, and
>   can be constructed to mimic hierarchical attributes.

So, really neither the length of path is important, nor structure of directories.